# reactReduxFirebase is undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux-firebase

I am using reactReduxFirebase to authenticate a user.Here is the code I am using to create the store.

```
import { reactReduxFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";
import firebase from "./services/firebase";

const createStoreWithFirebase = compose(reactReduxFirebase(firebase))(
  createStore
);
const store = createStoreWithFirebase(
  reducers,
  {},
  applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)
);
```

When logged reactReduxFirebase is undefined and I receive, and compose throws the error.

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

Comment: Are you importing the `compose` function?

Comment: yes I was, the compose function returned "function"

Comment: @GeoffreyHutson have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you are using version 3 of react-redux-firebase, from which you can no longer import `reactReduxFirebase`.

Try installing an older version of the package, by typing this in your terminal:

`npm i react-redux-firebase@2.2.4`